# Troubleshooting Rsyslog

Tags: linux

please help i am a new Linux user i cant seem to see where my problem is with this script.

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo mkdir -v /var/spool/rsyslog
if [ "$(lsb_release -ds | grep Ubuntu)" != "" ]; then
    sudo chown -R syslog:adm /var/spool/rsyslog
fi

sudo mkdir -i /etc/rsyslog.d/21-logzio-sample.conf
{#   -------------------------------------------------------
#        File Logging Directives for Logz.io
#   -------------------------------------------------------
$ModLoad imfile
$InputFilePollInterval 10
$PrivDropToGroup adm
$WorkDirectory /var/spool/rsyslog
# File access file:
$InputFileName PATH_TO_FILE
$InputFileTag TYPE:
$InputFileStateFile stat-TYPE
$InputFileSeverity info
$InputFilePersistStateInterval 20000
$InputRunFileMonitor
$template logzFormatFileTagName,"[{{API_TOKEN}}] <%pri%>%protocol-version% %timestamp:::date-rfc3339% %HOSTNAME% %app-name% %procid% %msgid% [type=TYPE] %msg%\n"
if $programname == 'TYPE' then @@{{LOGZ_LISTENER}}:5000;logzFormatFileTagName
if $programname == 'TYPE' then ~
} >> /etc/rsyslog.d/21-logzio-sample.conf

sudo service rsyslog restart
```

Comment: Please be more specific about what does not work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo mkdir -i /etc/rsyslog.d/21-logzio-sample.conf` will fail with

```
mkdir: invalid option -- 'i'
Try 'mkdir --help' for more information.
```

and about creating the `/etc/rsyslog.d/21-logzio-sample.conf` file, you should use something like this :

```
cat > filename <<- "EOF"
file contents
more contents
EOF
```

Script borrowed from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/806750/454520).